# Can End(F) be viewed as a pro-object in the category of finite dimensional algebras?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

In [EGNO](https://math.mit.edu/%7Eetingof/egnobookfinal.pdf) 1.10, we have essentially the following setup: given a $\mathbb{C}$-linear abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ and an exact faithful functor $F: \mathcal{A} \to Vec$ to the category of finite dimensional vectorspaces over $\mathbb{C}$, the natural endomorphisms of $F$ form an algebra $\operatorname{End}(F)$. This can be viewed as the categorical end of the bifunctor $\operatorname{Hom}(F-,F-)$. Letting $\operatorname{Coend}(F)$ denote the coend of $\operatorname{Hom}(F-,F-)^{*}$, one can check that $\operatorname{Coend}(F)^{*} \cong \operatorname{End}(F)$. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is equivalent to the category of finite dimensional comodules over $\operatorname{Coend}(F)$.

It is then claimed that $\mathcal{A}$ is equivalent to the category of continuous finite dimensional modules over $\operatorname{End}(F)$, where $\operatorname{End}(F)$ is given the initial topology for the maps $\operatorname{End}(F) \to \operatorname{End}(FX)$ sending $\eta \mapsto \eta_X$. (With each $\operatorname{End}(FX)$ given the discrete topology.)

Since $\operatorname{End}(F)$ is the dual algebra of a coalgebra, the general duality between $\mathbf{Coalg}$ and $\operatorname{Pro}(\mathbf{Alg}_{\text{f.d.}})$ tells us that $\operatorname{End}(F)$ can be viewed as a pro-object of finite dimensional algebras. The above topological construction brings stone duality to mind and suggests that $\operatorname{End}(F)$ should be able to to be viewed more directly as a pro-object with a diagram using only the algebras $\operatorname{End}(FX)$, without needing to reference the coend construction.

However, there aren't many obvious algebra morphisms between the different $\operatorname{End}(FX)$ that I can see. The only maps I can come up with are whenever $X$ is a retract of $Y$ we can compose with the section and retraction to get a morphism $\operatorname{End}(FX) \to \operatorname{End}(FY)$. This does form a cofiltered system of morphisms, but they don't commute with with the morphisms from $\operatorname{End}(F)$, and so this doesn't exhibit $\operatorname{End}(F)$ as a pro object.

Am I missing some obvious family of morphisms between the $\operatorname{End}(FX)$, or do you really need to use the coend construction to view $\operatorname{End}(F)$ as a pro-object?

Comment: Can't you just write $\mathcal{A}$ as a filtered colimit of its finitely generated abelian subcategories $\mathcal{B}$ and express $\mathrm{End}(F)$ as the limit of the rings $\mathrm{End}(F|_{\mathcal{B}})$?

Comment: @JonPridham Ah nice, so there you get maps between the Ends just from restriction. If you write that as an answer ill accept it

Comment: If $\mathcal{A}_X$ denotes the abelian subcategory of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $X$, then the kernel of the maps from $\operatorname{End}(F)$ to $\operatorname{End}(FX)$ and to $\operatorname{End}(F|_{\mathcal{A}_X})$ agree, so the topology induced by your example agrees with the one in EGNO.